# How to implement "Test Conenction" of TEMSProvider at runtime?

Tags: delphi, rad-server

In design mode, there is a "Test Connection" function on the right-click menu of TEMSProvider for testing the connection with the target RAD Server. But there seems no equivalent method of TEMSProvider that we can use at runtime. So is there a solution for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to test the connection?  You are either connected or not right?

Put the TEMSProvider and TBackendAuth on your Datamodule.  Fill in the appropriate URL and PORT, then in your code use the BackendAuth->Login() method to login with your credentials.

You'll either get connected or not, and if so you'll be logged in assuming you have setup credentials in the IB database or the emsserver.ini configuration file.